# In Express.js, is it safe to store any data in sessions?

Tags: node.js, security, session, cookies, express

I'm used to working solely with cookies.

With cookies, I would save a username and hash and perform a database query on each pageload, to ensure that the user has the correct password. I was about to do the same thing with sessions, when it occurred to me that sessions are not editable by the user.

Theoretically, I could say:

```
req.session.authenticated = true
```

and just test to see if the user has been authenticated, without rechecking if the password was correct.

Is this safe to do?
Or is it necessary to store the username and hash?

P.S. I'm using Express 4.8.6 with express-session 1.7.6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) doesn't store any working data in the cookies. Instead it stores a uuid in the cookie, and then matches that uuid to data in your session store (defaults to in-memory).

So if I visit your site, you'll give me a cookie containing `23949324`. Any data that you assign to my session will be stored somewhere not in my browser, my cookie remains `23949324`. Redis is a common session store.

You can do `req.session.creditcard = "4186xxxxxxxxxxx2"` and that's technically safe, at least in the realm of cookies. Realistically, you probably shouldn't be storing credit card data plaintext in your session store.

If you'd like persistant sessions I'd recommend [express-sessions](https://github.com/konteck/express-sessions).